# Overriding Geonode templatetag file

Tags: geonode, template

I'm customizing Geonode through the geonode-project template. To override geonode templates it's ok, but now I need to override a template tag file.

I customized the 'SUPPORTED_CRS' in my_geonode/settings.py to list the EPSG codes that I want, but, in order to show their names instead of the codes, I need to override the object EPSG_CODE_MATCHES that is defined in the geonode/layers/templatetags/layer_tags.py

How can I override this?

Answer (score 1):

Found it.
It's just a matter of creating a templatetags folder, with an `__init__.py` file inside, copy the layers_tags.py to this folder and edit it as wished. Run the application again so the .pyc file is generated. Now the customized file is recognized and overrides the one from geonode/layers/templatetags.